# DataTables: how to put variable in table initialization code

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters, datatables

I found that DataTables plug-in is very handsome and practical until you know at code start all necessary parameters. But, in my case I wish to change parameter scrollX according to detected document' height (60% of available height). I understand that here we talk about some kind of object but push and other tricks doesn't help. Here is problematic code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
table = $('#example').DataTable( {
language: {
info: "Show _START_ til _END_ of _TOTAL_ recs"   },
scrollY: "300px",
scrollX:        true,
scrollCollapse: true,
paging:         false,
rowReorder: false,
ordering: false,
fixedColumns:   {
    leftColumns: 2,
    rightColumns:0}     
   });
});
```

and instead "300px" I planned to put some kind of Javascript variable that contain document height, but classic object manipulation doesn't show result. So, I tried to check:

```
console.log(Table.scrollX);
```

but got error. Then tried to make table as public var but then got undefined value. Also:

```
table.push({'scrollX': '300px'});
```

and some weird combination, but nop. Any suggestion, please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var myScrollY = '300px';
  var table = $("#example").DataTable({
    scrollY: myScrollY
  });
);
```

Comment: Patrick G.: ouch, I couldn't recall this way! Clean and simply. Thank you man.

Comment: @LudusH Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Here the solution I'm using in my project:

You need to handle `resize` event. In the handler calculate the available area for `scrollable` part of the table:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
   var scrollWidth = "300px"; 
   // scrollWidth should be calculated based on your needs
   table.find( '.dataTables_scrollBody' ).width( scrollWidth );
})
```

I've done the same for `height`

**Update**:

Setting `scrollY: "300px"` works only for initialization.

When you change `height` of the document, the event `domready` is triggered and you have to recalculate new `height` of your `scrollable` area of `datatables`:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
   var newScrollHeight = Number($(window).height() - $('#IdOfAnElement').height() - other heights) + "px"; // 

   table.find( '.dataTables_scrollBody' ).height( newScrollHeight );
})
```

`.dataTables_scrollBody` is the element of `datatables` containing `scrollable` area.

Comment: Andrei Zhytkevich thank you man, but I couldn't implement your solution. Some helping clue, please?

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: I didn't understand your example. I tried your code in my case and wasn't able to make it works. Are you willing to explain it along with my code above? Thank you.